# AngularFire: Add Checkbox Data to Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to figure out how to add data from a form, specifically the data from checkboxes, to Firebase.

`providers` and `services` are two separate items in my Firebase. I'm using an `ng-repeat` on `providers` to generate my checkboxes.

```
<form ng-submit="addService(service)">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="service.name">
  <label for="{{ provider }}" ng-repeat="provider in providers">
    <input type="checkbox" name="provider" id="{{ provider }}" ng-model="provider.name">
    {{ provider.name }}
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And my `addService()` function looks like this:

```
$scope.addService = function(service) {
  services.$add({
    name: service.name
  })
};
```

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the `key` of each selected checkbox to that `addService()` function, so it appears like this:

```
"providers" : {
  "provider1" : { "name" : "The Whittington Hospital" },
  "provider2" : { "name" : "Homerton Hospital" },
  ...
},
"services" : {
  "service1" : {
    "name" : "Hernia Repair",
    "providers" : {
      "provider1" : true,
      "provider2" : true
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Any help with how to go about something like this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only wish to obtain a selected (or unselected) list of factories?

If so, an easy way would be that you create an object called `selection` holding which `factories` are selected. When the submit button is click, you can called the `Firebase` service to add an object with relevant info (name of the service, the list of selected factories), then clear the `selection` and so on.

You can also watch this selection collection using `$watchCollection` and therefore able to maintain a list of only selected items.

I've created a [demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/7atZslOPjrF96Ps41846/preview) here for illustrating the 1st solution.